# How to get table as array of arrays where each sub array is a column (not a row)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29246431/5783745) answer shows how to return a rails table as an array of arrays ***row wise***. How can this be achieved ***column wise***, that is, where each of the sub arrays is a column/attribute from the table?

For reference, here's how to return the table as array of arrays row wise

```
my_array = Mymodel.all.map {|e| e.attributes.values}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works, calls `SELECT` n times (n = Mymodel.column_names.count)

```
my_array = Mymodel.column_names.map { |column| Mymodel.all.map(&column.to_sym) }
```

This one will call `SELECT column_name` instead of `SELECT *` n times

```
my_array = Mymodel.column_names.map { |column| Mymodel.pluck(column.to_sym) }
```

Better and quicker solution is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54395303/4453714)

Answer (score 2):

A natural and reasonably database-efficient approach would be to use [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-transpose) on the array-of-arrays from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29246431/479863):

```
by_column = Mymodel.all.map { |e| e.attributes.values }.transpose
# Just add this ---------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comparison with other approaches,

```
bm =  Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report { my_array = User.column_names.map { |column| User.all.map(&column.to_sym) } }
  x.report { my_array = User.column_names.map { |column| User.pluck(column.to_sym) } }
  x.report { by_column = User.all.map { |e| e.attributes.values }.transpose }
end
```

In earlier two approaches provided by *Yuriy Verbitskiy*, first approach  load model N numbers of times & second one will fire `select` query N number of times.

And provided third approach will retrieve data in single query which optimise performance in superior way as shown in following result,

```
[
    [0] #<Benchmark::Tms:0xd6601f4 @label="", @real=0.05709833199989589, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.040000000000000036, @total=0.040000000000000036>,
    [1] #<Benchmark::Tms:0xd58e5f0 @label="", @real=0.02451071499990576, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.019999999999999907, @total=0.019999999999999907>,
    [2] #<Benchmark::Tms:0xd4e5eb4 @label="", @real=0.004674662000070384, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.010000000000000009, @total=0.010000000000000009>
]
```

Comment: I was trying same with `zip` to work with single database query but found this one which nearly gave same effect!

Comment: @ray Thanks for the benchmarks. One database hit and `Array#transpose` (which is implemented directly in C) should be pretty quick.

Comment: This is the quickest and readable way. I’ll edit my answer and upvote yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pluck` to get the column values and push it into your array. Something like...

```
your_array = []

Mymodel.column_names.each do |col|
  sub_arr = Mymodel.pluck(col.to_sym)
  your_array.push(sub_arr)
end
```